# feedback mail in android app

Tags: android, email, feedback

When the user fills the feedback form and then clicks on Submit button, the user information is then sent to my email address without asking the user to log into his/her account i.e. user can send feedback without our email credentials. Is it possible?

If yes then please give some hint.

```
btnfeedbacksubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent Email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        Email.setType("text/email");
        Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "email here" });
        Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback");
        Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(Email, "Sending Feedback:"));

    }
});
```

Comment: if its android, the user is almost always logged in..and the email request would be handled by the Gmail App???

Comment: yes do u have any solution?

Comment: Is this [blog post](http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/10/send-mail-from-android-application.html) will help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
 import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.mail.*;

import javax.mail.internet.*;

import com.sun.mail.smtp.*;

public class Distribution {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtps.host","smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtps.auth","true");
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("mail@tovare.com"));;
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
    InternetAddress.parse("tov.are.jacobsen@iss.no", false));
    msg.setSubject("Heisann "+System.currentTimeMillis());
    msg.setText("Med vennlig hilsennTov Are Jacobsen");
    msg.setHeader("X-Mailer", "Tov Are's program");
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    SMTPTransport t =
        (SMTPTransport)session.getTransport("smtps");
    t.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "admin@tovare.com", "<insert password here>");
    t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    System.out.println("Response: " + t.getLastServerResponse());
    t.close();
}
}
```

Comment: plz help me how can i implement this coding in android java file? if anyone knows the programming of this file then pease edit the file send to me... please help... thank u...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**BackgroundMailLibrary**](https://github.com/kristijandraca/BackgroundMailLibrary) for sending mail in background, in your app!

but many of them recommend to give the feedback via Google play (*click on the rate button should open your app in Googlplay*) give it a try with this:

[appirater](https://github.com/sbstrm/appirater-android)

[AppRater](https://github.com/delight-im/AppRater)

[RateMeMaybe](https://github.com/Kopfgeldjaeger/RateMeMaybe)